# ListViewAdapter different styles for rows

Tags: android

in my app, I have a `ExpandableListView` with a `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. The method `getChildView` looks like:

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyCustomObject myObject = (MyCustomObject)getGroup(groupPosition)).getValue().get(childPosition);
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView lbl = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbl);
        lbl.setText(myObject.getText());

        return convertView;
    }
```

I would like to change the background (and others features) of the layout depending on a property on `myObject`. My first attempt was to define a different style and try to change the style of the view dynamically, but this is not possible.

What is the best and most efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Additionally to the background, what else do you want to change?

Comment: I am not sure yet, but let say I want to add an icon ( or change its visibility depending on the property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this dynamically without any issue. Talking very informally, you have the whole row layout in your `convertView` instance. If you want to change the background, just call `convertView.setBackground(...)`. If you have more elements in your layout, just get them using `convertView.findElementById(R.id...)`, and then make them the changes you need.

Answer (score 0):

`getChildView()` gives you the `groupPosition` and `childPosition`. In order to determine which one is the current "child `View`" you need to use these two parameters (i.e. `switch` `groupPosition` and create as many cases as groups you have). In each of these cases you will inflate and return the corresponding `View` for the row and use `myObject` to set any values you want to display in the corresponding child of row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I normally do:

First make a list_item.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <LinearLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/colorBar"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="32dp"
           android:orientation="vertical"/>
  <TextView
           android:id="@+id/mytextView1"
           android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Then create a class in your BaseExpandableListAdapter:

```
 public static class Row{
      LinearLayout m_llColorBar;
      TextView m_myTextView;

  }
```

And do this in your getChildView() Method

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    // Row Class reference
    Row curRow;

    // Reference to your custom object Parent
    MyCustomObject myObject = (MyCustomObject)getGroup(groupPosition)).getValue().get(childPosition);

    // Context should be passed into Constructor
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    // If convertView is null, we need to create a new Child Layout
    if(convertView == null)
    {
      curRow = new Row();
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
      curRow.m_llColorBar = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.colorBar);
      curRow.m_myTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView1);

      // Sets a unique tag for the current row
      convertView.setTag(curRow);

     // Else,
    }else{

       // Recycle the view 
       curRow = (Row) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Set the Text View to the Object's Text
    curRow.m_myTextView.setText(myObject.getText());

    // If the Object's Text is Some value
    if(myObject.getText().equals("Some Value")){

      // Make the Bar the Dark Holo Blue
      curRow.m_llColorBar.setBackground(context.getResources().getColor(
               android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));

    }else if(myObject.getText().equals("Some Other Value")){

      // Make the Bar the Dark Holo Orange
      curRow.m_llColorBar.setBackground(context.getResources().getColor(
               android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));
    }else{

      // Make the Bar the Dark Holo Red
      curRow.m_llColorBar.setBackground(context.getResources().getColor(
               android.R.color.holo_red_dark));

    }

    // Return the View
    return convertView;
}
```

And this illustrates how to make your row items based on content look different.

1. Just a simple Class holding your UI Elements
2. Reference this in your getChildView()
3. Initialize it if the View is null
4. Use the View to get your Items
5. then a for loop in your getChildView() method.

And you can do this with any Widget So say you have an `ImageView` and multiple images you may want to include in your row based on that content. Just Add the `ImageView` reference to the Simple `Class` Row and then use an if Statement to add the new `ImageView` src dynamically based on text in your object.